# jQuery $.post to Django returns "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: django, jquery

I am working on the jQuery tutorial ([Link](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery)) but have been stuck at the section, "RATE ME: USING AJAX"

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // generate markup
   $("#rating").append("Please rate: ");

   for ( var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ )
     $("#rating").append("<a href='#'>" + i + "</a> ");

   // add markup to container and apply click handlers to anchors
   $("#rating a").click(function(e){
     // stop normal link click
     e.preventDefault();

     // send request
     $.post("/vote", {rating: $(this).html()}, function(xml) {
       // format and output result
       $("#rating div").html(
         "Thanks for rating, current average: " +
         $("average", xml).text() +
         ", number of votes: " +
         $("count", xml).text()
       );
     });
   });
 });
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^rating/$', 'ajax_rating.views.rating'),
    (r'^vote/$', 'ajax_rating.views.vote'),
)
```

views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def vote(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        rating = request['rating']
        f = open('ratings.dat', 'w')
        votes = json.load(f)
        votes.append(rating)
        f.close()
        dict = {}
        total_rating = sum(votes)
        dict['count'] = len(votes)
        dict['avg'] = total_rating / dict['count']
        return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('xml', dict), 'application/xml')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

Basically, the html offers the user to make a choice between 1 to 5 (anchors with class=rating). Once a choice is clicked, the #rating div would get refreshed with the calculated result returned from the server.

**Problem:** I am getting "HTTP 500 Internal Server Error" when I click on a choice. The error happens even before the request hits the view function, vote(request). I have tried to figure out why the error but don't have any clues. I don't think it has anything to do with csrf as I am using @csrf_exempt on the view function and have taken out 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' from MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Please help~~ thanks to you experts

Comment: Can you turn on debug mode to see what the 500 is?

Comment: The debug mode in on already. But, somehow, the page just remains the same.

Comment: If you use firebug in FF or developer tools in Chrome, you can typically inspect the 500 response to find out what it says. Try clicking on it in the console.

Comment: I was trying to do that in Chrome but wasn't sure if it had the capability to allow me to view the details of the 500 response. Now that you have confirmed that for me. I'll figure it out how to do that in Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: With the console tab open, just click the url of the request that generated the 500 response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rating` would not be a valid key on `request`.  You are probably looking for `request.POST['rating']`.  Or, to be safe so that you don't throw even more key errors:

```
rating = request.POST.get('rating', None)
if rating is None:
    return HttpResponse(status=400) ## or some error.
```

Answer (score 22):

I believe the POST should go to the URL `/vote/` and not just `/vote`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me with a 500 error I was getting for hours. Out of curiosity, any particular reason POST needs a URL ending in with a slash? Seems like a silly thing to make your entire call not work.

Comment: I had this same problem. Sending a POST request to `www.example.com/data` did not work and returned HTTP 500, but `www.example.com/data/` fixed the problem returning HTTP 200.

Comment: If the URL is defined with a slash at the end in urls.py then you need the slash. A auto-redirect doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @Nitrex88 Presumably `/vote/` is the correct url, and `APPEND_SLASH` setting causes a redirect. But it just makes the user visit the new url, it doesn't cause a post request with the same data to be made to the new url.

Comment: It worked for me as well. It seems very ridiculous though!!